# Regex to match multiple spaces but not if they are after a period

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Example: `My Name is  Mohit.     Surname is  Kumar`.

The regex should only match the spaces after `is` as there are multiple spaces after it, but not after other words as there is only one space after them and not after `Mohit.` as there is a period after the word.

I have tried

1. `(?<!\.)\s{2,}`
2. `(?<!\.)\s+`

but both these expressions are matching multiple spaces after `Mohit.` expect for the first space.
I'm testing my regex at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Use `(?<![.\s])\s{2,}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
/(?<!\.|\s)\s{2,}/gm
```

See demo: https://regex101.com/r/imlcbQ/1

Comment: Thanks, this works only for period. Was missing the OR part.

Comment: @MOHITKUMAR Do not use OR, it is extra backtracking. Use `(?<![.\s])` instead.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew for the tip and lesson.
But can you explain it a little bit how this works as Regex101 explanation is going above my head as my understanding is it does not match if preceding character is `.` or `\s`, but this should not match any multiple spaces at all.

Comment: @MOHITKUMAR `(?<!\.|\s)` = `(?<![.\s])` in terms of result since both mean "not immediately preceded with a `.` or whitespace"

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `(?<=\w)\s{2,}`

It works because:

- If has a positive lookbehind, checking that there's a word character.
- Then, it matches for two or more spaces.

In effect, it will match 2+ spaces as long as they are proceeded by a word character. As a dot is not a word character, the spaces after the dot won't be considered.

Comment: This will not match even if there is question mark (?). But it should only not match when there is a period(.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer though as this helped me in understanding my other problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working regular expression :

```
(?<=\S)(?<!\.)\s{2,}
```

- **(?<=\S)** : Positive lookbehind assertion that matches a position right after a non-whitespace character.
- **(?<!.)** : Negative lookbehind assertion that ensures the match is not preceded by a period.
- **\s{2,}** : Matches two or more consecutive whitespace characters.

regex101 : https://regex101.com/r/CWyQah/1

Comment: This is not matching even if there is question mark (?). But it should only not match when there is a period(.)